# Is Mysql NOW() DETERMINISTIC

Tags: mysql, deterministic

When you mark a MySQL function as `DETERMINISTIC`, documentation says

> A routine is considered “deterministic” if it always produces the same result for the same input parameters, and “not deterministic” otherwise.

Is it true along time? Does a `DETERMINISTIC` function have to return the same results if called in different client session? Or in different queries in a session?

**In other words, would `NOW()` be considered as `DETERMINISTIC`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOW() is very much non-deterministic, just by the definition you gave.  The point of deterministic is that it allows various optimizations based on assumptions that wouldn't hold if your results depends on the current time.
See http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,406891,406895#msg-406895 for an example discussion.

Comment: Isn't `NOW()` constant inside a query? A `SELECT NOW() FROM...` query that takes few seconds returns the same values, implying that `NOW()` is considered as constant during the query execution, doesn't it?

Comment: Something is deterministic iff it always returns precisely the same value when invoked with the same parameters. Deterministic operations can be the subject of common subexpression elimination (a type of program transformation used in automated optimization). `NOW()` isn't deterministic, your intuition to the contrary notwithstanding.

Comment: Okay, I thought "invoked multiple times" referred to multiple invocations in the same query (so `RAND()` wouldn't be deterministic), not among different queries.

Answer (score 1):

According to definition `NOW()` is non-deterministic. If it was deterministic, it should be a constant as it takes 0 parameters. So it would have produced the same result in every call.

Comment: "Same result" even among time? So if I have a function involving `NOW()`, it must be `DETERMINISTIC`, regardless the fact that `NOW()` returns always the same result when used inside a query like `SELECT`?

Comment: @Xenos "Same result" even among time?" - yes, it must be the same result regardless of time. The simple deterministic function is sin(x).